# How to prove a Ramanujan-type series for Pi?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am referring to Ramanujan series or the Chudnovsky series or any similar series converging fast. When we see the formula we go WOW but is there a proof available for some series like that? Didn't Ramanujan provide a proof in his letters to Cambridge University or anywhere else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you Google it I believe there proofs somewhere

Comment: I 've done that but came up with nothing..

Comment: See this post https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-1.html?m=0

Answer (score 2):

Re-typeset version of Ramanujan's 1914 article *Modular equations and approximations to π*:
http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram06.pdf
(number 6 from http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/html/published_papers.html).

Lorenz Milla, *A detailed proof of the Chudnovsky formula with means of basic complex analysis*:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00533.

Comment: Thanks! really detailed but I 've give it a shot to follow it.